# Determine an element's custom CSS cursor hotspot coordinates from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, mouse-cursor

When I attempt to get the full CSS cursor definition of an HTML element in JavaScript, it omits the hotspot (target pixel) coordinates for some reason and is resulting in my cursor resetting its hotspot to the top-left pixel of the cursor image (i.e. not a good thing).

[Problem demonstrated in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ck3nd/).

**Update:** It appears to only be this way in some browsers, specifically (in my tests) Mac Chrome and Safari.

**Update 2:** Looks like this is actually fixed in the latest nightly build of WebKit (8536.26.17, 537+), so I guess there's no real answer required besides it's a bug, and has already been fixed.

For example:

```
var elem = document.createElement("div");
elem.style.cursor = "url('path/to/cursor') 9 9, auto";
console.log( elem.style.cursor );
```

Outputs:

```
url(path/to/cursor), auto
```

Is there any way to get those coordinates from the style once they've been set?? I tried `window.getComputedStyle()` but it has the same result.

This seems like a pretty major oversight to me. Is that information just lost and no longer retrievable?

Comment: It's the center of the icon here: Chrome 27, Firefox 18.

Comment: Interesting. I'm on Chrome 24, the latest on Mac.

Comment: @chaiguy Do you have other browsers installed? If yes, test in them.

Comment: @chaiguy Chrome 27 is Canary. I have the same result in Chrome 24 (also WinXP)

Comment: It actually works correctly in Firefox for Mac, but Safari is the same as Chrome.

Comment: have you cleared your caches?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from looking at the CSS 2.1 Specification, the X and Y coordinates are not included:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/ui.html#cursor-props

Also, the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/cursor) lists the X,Y coordinates as "experimental."

If something isn't in the specification then you can expect browsers to have different, and sometimes conflicting, implementations of the property.

Comment: That may be the case, but I mean really, without those coordinates a custom cursor is all but pointless.

Comment: If you look at the value returned by `test.style.cursor`, it excludes the coordinates, and hence when you reset it, it causes the bug. Whether it's pointless to exclude or not is irrelevant, you should develop a workaround so the feature works. Later, when the problem is fixed, you can update your code.